# Existing classes are not working in new project with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, touch-event

I wrote an app with 1 activity and 1 view, so it gives me the coordinates of my fingers i put on the screen. Worked perfectly.

The Problem is now: I Created a new App with more than 1 Activity so i can change between them with intents. also worked fine. But one Activity should be the one wich give me my finger positions. So i Copyed the class and activity put them into the manifest. And made a Button and a intend for to run it.
So when i try to run it it creates the class but doesnt react on my onTouchEvents anymore...
and i have no clue why. i hope i explained my problem well enough for u guys to understand.

So this is my main activity. starts the menu with the option to go to the not working class

```
public class V1_2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn_1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_v1_2);

        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( btn_1.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Obj_recog.class));
        }
    }
```

This is now the activity wich creates the touchpiont class for the touchevents

```
public class Obj_recog extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    touchtest TP;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blank);
        TP = new touchtest(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

And now an example of what doesnt work here but worked at the last project the same way

```
public class touchtest extends View{

    public touchtest(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("worked", "worked");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.d("Touch", "TOUCH!!!!");
        return true;
    }

}
```

So i get the message that it "worked" but it doesnt react on touchevents like it used to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be worked if you add touchtest view as your main view by using setcontentview and then 
add touchlistener on that view and call your ontouchevent from your touchtest class. code will be like --

```
 TP = new touchtest(this);
    setContentView(TP);
    TP.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            TP.onTouchEvent(event);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

i think should change this approach find an alternative way to implement for which you are going in this way.

In this way you can keep your blank layout and also TP.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
TP = new touchtest(this);
    rl.addView(TP);

    TP.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            TP.onTouchEvent(event);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks, that helped a lot. when i insert setContentView(TP); it works fine, but is there a way in wich a can keep my layout? wich i created in xml..

Comment: In order to do that you can give an id to your layout and then get that layout in class and add TP to that layout. I have add a code section above.

Comment: up vote me & also mark it right if you find this as right answer please.